# Find all combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, stored-procedures

My teacher asks an algorithm that find all combinations. I have a set of data and the length can be variable. So combinations should be like this:

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
...
ccbc
ccca
cccb
cccc
```

They will be stored in the "word" table that contains a single varchar field.
I did it with  loop because I don't like recursivity and jt has better performance:

```
DROP PROCEDURE combi;
CREATE PROCEDURE combi
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM word
    DECLARE @i BIGINT
    DECLARE @j INT
    DECLARE @word NVARCHAR(24)
    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(62)
    DECLARE @combinations BIGINT
    DECLARE @currentlength TINYINT
    DECLARE @maxcurrentlength TINYINT
    SET @maxcurrentlength=4
    SET @str='azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN0123456789' -- length=62
    SET @currentlength=1
    -- loop on the length of the text
    WHILE @currentlength<=@maxcurrentlength BEGIN
        SET @combinations=POWER(62,@currentlength)
        SET @i=0
        -- get all combinations
        WHILE i<@combinations BEGIN
            SET @word=''
            SET @j=0
            -- generate word
            WHILE @j<@currentlength BEGIN
                SET @word=@word+SUBSTRING(@str, (FLOOR(@i / POWER(62,@currentlength-@j-1) ) % 62) +1, 1)
                SET @j=@j+1
            END
            INSERT INTO word VALUES (@word)
            SET @i=@i+1
        END
        SET @currentlength=@currentlength+1
    END
END;
EXEC combi;
```

The problem is when I use a length of 8, my server crashes: it seems that `POWER(62,@currentlength-@j-1)` is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried any answer?

Comment: i'm testing ssnobody's answer on a length of 8... My computer is currently running since saturday

Comment: it is a huge number of combinations.

Comment: I know... I asked my SQL Server teacher to give us a shorten password to find. Furthermore, it is slower than native code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused about how you ask the question. You ask to "find all combinations" which could very easily be done with CROSS JOIN. If you need to get a length of 4 then you join the table with available values to itself 4 times and you are pretty much done. If you need to get the strings in 1 field you could concatenate them in the select. Like this:

```
declare @values table (
value nvarchar(100))

insert @values values ('a'),('b'),('c')

select v1.value+v2.value+v3.value+v4.value
from @values v1 cross join 
    @values v2 cross join
    @values v3 cross join
    @values v4
order by v1.value+v2.value+v3.value+v4.value
```

Comment: I'm currently looking into some tricks to get in the order of power(18,18) without cross joking 18 times. Anyone got some clever ideas?

Comment: I'm looking at using cte recursion to do it, although the poster stated he doesn't like recursion (and I agree it's problematic), this seems like a good possible use of cte recursion.

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey i'm playing around with it now but there are some serious challenges! cross join creates new columns for each recursion and union all doesnt play nice with uneven datasets. so far there also does not seem to be a way to refer to a specific recursion making it dificult to use the results and finally... your not allowed to aggregate inside the recursions...

Comment: Tristan, yes, I looked at it but couldn't make it work either, and moved on!

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey want to continue this chat on email or something? I think we are 1 or 2 comments away from a warning from stackoverflow to not use the comments for discussion, but i'm interested to hear where you headed with this.

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey: You may be interested in the recursive CTE I added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **generic solution** using a **recursive CTE**:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i nchar(1))
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')

;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT cast(i AS nvarchar(4000)) AS combo, 1 AS ct
   FROM   t

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT cte.combo + t.i, ct + 1
   FROM   cte
   CROSS  JOIN t
   WHERE  ct <= 4  -- your maximum length
   )
SELECT combo
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY ct, combo
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c551f/1)

You must be aware that the number of results grows **exponentially** with the maximum length, so performance deteriorates rapidly with growing maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely overflowing the int type you are passing to `POWER()` as the [documentation for power](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) suggests `POWER()` returns the same type you feed it.

Try using:

```
SET @word=@word+SUBSTRING(@str, (FLOOR(@i / POWER(CAST(62 AS BIGINT),@currentlength-@j-1) ) % 62) +1, 1)
```

Comment: I'm testing, it seems you have the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parameterise it so that you can set the required length then this algorithm would do it and it's more relational database orientated.

```
declare @characters table (character nchar(1))
declare @words table (word nvarchar(100))
insert @characters values ('a'),('b'),('c')
INSERT @words (word ) VALUEs ('')
DECLARE @Required_length int
DECLARE @length int
SET @Required_length = 4
SET @length  = 0
WHILE @length <= @Required_length
BEGIN
SET @length  = @length+1
INSERT @words (word ) 
SELECT w.word + c.character
FROM @words w JOIN  @characters c ON LEN(w.word) = @length-1
END
SELECT word from @words where len(word) = @Required_length
```

- Start with a zero length word
- Add all the possible characters to the zero length word to get all
  the one character words
- Add all the possible characters to the end of  all the one character
  words to get all the two character words
- Add all the possible characters to the end of all the two character words
  to get all the three character words
- etc....

You can make it run more efficiently by including the length as a column in the word table so that you don't need to calculate the lengths when you're filtering by them but as this has been set by your teacher I'm not going to do all your work for you

Answer (score 0):

First insert of all characters

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
create table ##chars (col char(1))
declare @i int 
set @i=65
while @i<=90  /* A-Z */
begin
  insert into ##chars values( CHAR(@i))
  set @i=@i+1
end
set @i=97
while @i<=122 /* a-z */
begin
  insert into ##chars values( CHAR(@i))
  set @i=@i+1
end
set @i=48
while @i<=57  /* 0-9 */
begin
  insert into ##chars values( CHAR(@i))
  set @i=@i+1
end
```

Now, set number for combinations

```
create table ##result(word varchar(10))
declare @wide int
set @wide=4    /* set how many combinations are calculated  */


insert into ##result select * from ##chars
while @wide>1
begin
    begin tran w
    insert into ##result select a.word+b.col from ##result a, ##chars b
    commit tran w
set @wide=@wide-1
end
select * from ##result
/*
drop table ##chars
drop table ##result
*/
```